# SQL - Remove Duplicates in Single Field

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Company.CompanyName
      ,Student.Status
      ,Student.Level
      ,Student.PlacementYear
      ,Company.CompanyCode
      ,Company.HREmail
      ,Company.Telephone
      ,Company.HRContact
      ,PlacedStudents.DateAdded 
FROM Student 
    RIGHT JOIN (Company INNER JOIN PlacedStudents 
                        ON Company.CompanyCode = PlacedStudents.CompanyCode) 
           ON Student.StudentNo = PlacedStudents.StudentNo 
WHERE (((Student.PlacementYear)=" & Year & ")) 
    AND((Student.Status)<>'Still Seeking YOPE') 
ORDER BY Company.CompanyName
```

I have this SQL Query which pulls HR Contacts from Companies where students are currently placed. However, there are multiple students at one company so when I run the query there are duplicates. I'm fairly new to SQL, I tried DISTINCT, however it didn't seem to do anything, the duplicates remained.

How can I remove duplicates in the CompanyCode field so that the Company only appears once when the query is run.

Below is an image of what happens when I run query. Hopefully this makes sense?
[image: http://s3.postimg.org/jarduw9pf/REPORT.png]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and include sample data and desired results.  Pay particular attention to the results you want when multiple students are at a company.

Comment: Which student do you want to get for a company if there are several placed? If you need a list of companies, you need to select from Company table.

Answer (score 1):

This query should give you companies that have placed students:

```
SELECT Company.CompanyName
      ,Company.CompanyCode
      ,Company.HREmail
      ,Company.Telephone
      ,Company.HRContact
FROM Company 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PlacedStudents INNER JOIN 
               Student ON Student.StudentNo = PlacedStudents.StudentNo 
                        WHERE Company.CompanyCode = PlacedStudents.CompanyCode
                         AND Student.PlacementYear =" & Year & " 
                         AND Student.Status <>'Still Seeking YOPE')
ORDER BY Company.CompanyName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is asking for HR Contacts from Companies where students are placed. I assume this means if you have 1, 2 or 1,000,000 students at a single company, you only want to see the company listed once?

Your current query is returning information from STUDENT and PLACEDSTUDENTS which is going to result in output like

```
COMPANY_A STUDENT01 .........
COMPANY_A STUDENT02 .........
COMPANY_A STUDENT03 .........
```

and so on.

If so, and taking a best guess (since I can't know what's in STUDENT or PLACEDSTUDENTS tables), try not including anything related to STUDENT in the SELECT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Company.CompanyName, Company.CompanyCode, Company.HREmail, 
Company.Telephone, Company.HRContact FROM
```

I'll be happy to help more if you can provide more information about the structure of the tables and some examples of data, AND what you actually want from the query.